# passing this (the object) into one of the objects methods nested methods

Tags: javascript, dom, object, parameters, this

Sorry for the long winded title, but I think it summaries my problem

I have created a jsfiddle to cut down and create a simplified problem of my dilemma
http://jsfiddle.net/afw6k/3/

```
<input id="txtA"/>
<!-- after setupOnclick is executed my onlick for txtA should be onclick="someObj.log("Clicked!")"-->
<script>
    function someObject(field){
        this.field = field;

        this.log = function(msg){
            if(this.field.value != "") this.field.value += ", ";
            this.field.value += msg
        }

        this.setupOnlick = function(){ 
            field.onlick = function(){//So how do I pass this (as in someObject) to this?
                this.log("Clicked!"); //As if I have written someObj.log("Clicked!");
            }
        }
    }

    var someObj = new someObject(document.getElementById("txtA"));
    someObj.setupOnlick();
</script>
```

I'm not trying to simply write something to a textbox when clicked, but the above is a simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish here.

Passing this (the object) into an objects functions nested function

Or is there a far better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save `this` in a variable:

```
    this.setupOnlick = function(){ 
        var theObj = this;
        field.onlick = function(){//So how do I pass this (as in someObject) to this?
            theObj.log("Clicked!"); //As if I have written someObj.log("Clicked!");
        }
    }
```

The value of `this` is just a value, so it can be copied to another variable. The variable "theObj" will remain in scope of the "click" handler when it runs.

Comment: We really need a canonical question for closing dups like this.

Comment: @MattBall yes - I wish there were some way of making sure that this general topic were forced in front of everybody casually strolling into the role of JavaScript developer :-)

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response. Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I think the problem is everybody interprets and words the question differently so it's have to discover the related questions. It just confuses me how it loses scope of the this variable, or is it only in scope up to one level down?

Comment: @Emdiesse no worries - you're exactly right; it's a "family" of questions, all with the same basic answer.  A key thing to understand: in JavaScript, `this` is set on **every function call**. It's not an intrinsic property of a function; it's an **effect** of calling a function, in other words. However, it's also possible to save it, as in my answer, because it's just an ordinary reference to an object.

Comment: Cheers again, it all makes sense to me now. This is one of them very basic concepts I have been struggling to find an answer for, but now it all makes sense :)